# Why does Google Location History stay in the same place when I go out?

Tags: google-location-history

What's happening is that I go out and about and at the end of the day I check the location history and it says that I've been at my house all day when I've been out. I take my phone with me and it stays on, the GPS is on.

I do have a tab that stays at home but there's no location settings allowed for it, there isn't even a glimpse of the location to out of my house. It looks like it's tracking my tab but it's not set for location data to be used for apps. I do not have any apps on the tab that would need my location anyway, but the GPS is off on it so it wouldn't be able to track it besides using the WiFi location.

The location simply does not move, it might go out on the street but there's no indication whatsoever I went anywhere other than my house.

Comment: Same problem here, location history updates on more recent android with samsung phone seem to be many hours apart. I would prefer something like 5 minutes or less between location history updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Latitude than sorry [it has been retired](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3001634?hl=en)

Instead use [Google+ from here](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354?hl=en)

Comment: So it doesn't work anymore? If so what are the incorrect location marks for? Also, my friend still uses it and it works for him.